# Rails: Query across tables without JOIN

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason cannot get this to work. I've been going through Code School's lessons and watched this video:
http://railsforzombies.org/levels/2
at the 9:13 mark he queries across models.. I am just trying to do the same..

This is what I've done.. I have two models.. User and Product
my relationships:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end
```

and then my schema

```
   create_table "products", force: true do |t|
     t.integer  "upc"
     t.string   "description"
     t.integer  "user_id"
     t.datetime "created_at"
     t.datetime "updated_at"
   end 

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
     t.string   "name"
     t.datetime "created_at"
     t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

then finally, the actual query..

```
s = Product.find(1)

Product Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Product id: 1, upc: 1, description: "Desc. 1", user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-04-16 16:14:48", updated_at: "2015-04-16 16:14:48">
```

and then I just want to return the name of the user who owns the first product.. like so

```
s.user.name
```

this gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<Product:0x00000005593850>
```

but it is not working, What can be the issue here?

Comment: could you paste the result of the query when you do the `Product.find(1)`

Comment: What is the error you are getting??

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I updated the code with the response of the first query..

Comment: try user.products.find..which will give you all user products and vice-versa if you try product.user to get user

Comment: @ToddT no I meant the actual product data, the saved data, just to make sure the product has a `user_id` to be more specific

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I THINK? you can see the data here https://app-trimakas-5.c9.io/products its my dev box from Cloud9

Comment: @ToddT well this is kinda weird, cause the assocciation is already in the code, maybe your issue is that your classes were not loaded after you added the relation, you could try running `reload!` then fetch the product again, or simple close the console and start it again to make sure all the models are loaded with the correct assocciations.

Comment: ToddT are you trying this in a rails console? did you reload it after the change?

Comment: @astreal yep I am using the rails console and I reloaded and still getting it.. I don't know what's wrong.. argghh